# How to create columns with the names from a sqlite table in a dataGridView

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm trying to search for a code entered by the user in a sqlite table if it's found add the row to a `dataGridView`. the problem is that the code I'm using clears the datagrid every time I add a new row.

Here is the code I'm using

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

String insSQL = "select * from Produtos where codigo =" + txtCodigo.Text;
String strConn = @"Data Source=C:\caixa.sqlite";

SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(strConn);

SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(insSQL, strConn);
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridViewProdutos.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

I tried to change the `dataGridViewProdutos.datasource` to `dataGridViewProdutos.Rows.add(dt);` them it adds a row but always empty.

Comment: Have you check to see if you are getting data back? Why dt.DefaultView just set it to the DataTable should work dataGridViewProdutos.DataSource = dt;.

Comment: This link may hlep http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fbk67b6z(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it removing the DataTable dt = new DataTable(); from the loop. I also changed the dt.DefeulView to only dt as sugested by N4TKD and I`m seeing no diference so I`m using it.

Also thanks for the links it was very helpfull since I was struggling to make my colums fill the dataGridView space.